# SELF JOIN Unique Resultset Issue - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have a table as below

```
ID | CID

1  | 3
2  | 0
3  | 4
4  | 0
5  | 0
6  | 3
```

Below is the SQL query I use which is SELF JOIN.

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM `tbl_a` AS t1 JOIN `tbl_a` AS t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.CID
```

Which gives me O/P as below.

```
ID | CID

3  | 4
4  | 0
```

But what I want as an O/P is `1,3,4,6`.

Logic of the O/P is Rows IDs or CIDs which are being used. If I explain more When the ID is 1 CID 3, When the ID is 3 CID is 4, When the ID is 6 CID is 3. When I get the unique IDs & CIDs that are used in the table would be `1,3,4,6`.

Final Correct O/P Required is below.

```
ID  

1   
3   
4   
6
```

How can I get it done?

Comment: shouldn't be t1.Id = t2.CID ? Also, your expected output, is {1,3} and {4,6} ? please format so it would be more clear

Comment: You are only selecting columns from t1. Try `SELECT * FROM A t1 JOIN B t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;`

Comment: As currently stated, your sample output is wrong and your question does not make sense.

Comment: @ Hunter McMillen - Where do you see two separate tables here. And on `SELF JOIN` you can not use `SELECT *`. You will get a problem with ambiguous field names.

Comment: I think you want a recursive self-join, until some CID field equals to any previous ID, right ?

Comment: I'm really sorry I don't understand the concept behind recursive self-join. But the O/P I want have been showed in the question. I'm trying my best to get it. Still working on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For starters, what do you mean by "O/P"? Secondly, your query doesn't return the results stated from the data supplied - see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b36bf/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do. I think you are saying you want the ID of rows that have a non-zero CID or that are referenced by the CID column. (?) Try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM tbl_a AS t1 WHERE CID <> 0 OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_a AS t2 WHERE t2.CID = t1.ID) ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t2.ID
FROM `tbl_a` AS t1 JOIN `tbl_a` AS t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.CID
OR t2.ID = t1.CID
GROUP BY t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you want:

```
select ID
from tbl_a
where id in (3, 4) or cid in (3, 4);
```